# java - what does casting a passed reference do

Tags: java

I remember reading "**when we pass object to methods in java we pass them as reference but assigning a new value to the reference in method doesn't change the object because the references are passed by value and the value is simply replaced by the new one**"

But, what if we're doing something else besides assignment, for example:

```
//Main.java
public class Main{  
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Object A = new String("newString");
    mUtil mutil = new mUtil();
    System.out.println(A.toString());
    mutil.someMethod(A);
    A = new Object(); //shouldn't this throw an exception because the A has been cast to a String

  }
}

//mUtil.java
public class mUtil{
  mUtil(){} //no-args constructor
public void someMethod(Object a){
      a = (String)a;
      System.out.println("From someMethod: "+a.toString());
  }
}
```

As I've commented, shouldn't that line throw an exception?

Comment: Why do you expect it to throw one? The compile type is still an `Object`.

Comment: Why should it throw an exception? The `a` you pass in actually **is** a `String` object, so casting it to `String` will succeed. However, that line is pointless, since `a = (String) a` will always do one of two things: Assign `a` the value it already had (note: casting doesn't *change* anything about the value) or throw an exception if `a` isn't a `String` to begin wiith.

Comment: @DorianGray , meaning it's not downcasted to a different objects and no generality is loss?

Comment: Casting doesn't change the object/reference at all. Casting is there to tell the compiler, yes, this thing that's officially an "Object" is really a "String". Really, trust me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting `a` does not change `a`, it merely shows the code afterwards what `a` should be interpreted as (here: String).